# Using Owin Self-Host ASP.Net API2 Can't Receive POST Request with data in body instead of query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, owin, self-hosting

I been making a Bot to Receive notification from a Ark: Survival Evolved Game Server and Send them to the Steam account of the player using steam chat system !

well, everything was done greatly with no problem, I tested my work using data sent from a query string, and it works and send the messages etc.

but now that i check using the game server, it won't work.

The Problem, seems to be coming from sending the HTTP POST Request with body content instead of query string as my app will not receive them.

I have made a lot of examples to receive the POST requests but non seems to work,
I hope someone here know how to fix this, I lost all hope as i been working on this for over 5 hours and even ask about it in C# SOChat.

Here is my code : https://github.com/LuckyPed/Ark-Steam-Notifier-Console/blob/Post-Data/ArkSteamNotifier/ValuesController.cs

Non of these seems to work :

```
    public void Post1(string key, ulong steamid, string notetitle, string message)
    {
        if (!Program.settings.UnSub.Contains(steamid))
        {
            SteamID SID = new SteamID(steamid);
            Program.steamFriends.SendChatMessage(SID, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, System.DateTime.UtcNow + " UTC ( GMT ) : " + notetitle);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Program.steamFriends.SendChatMessage(SID, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, message);
        }
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]string key,[FromBody]ulong steamid,[FromBody]string notetitle,[FromBody]string message)
    {
        if (!Program.settings.UnSub.Contains(steamid))
        {
            SteamID SID = new SteamID(steamid);
            Program.steamFriends.SendChatMessage(SID, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, System.DateTime.UtcNow + " UTC ( GMT ) : " + notetitle);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Program.steamFriends.SendChatMessage(SID, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, message);
        }
    }

    public class MyFormData
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]MyFormData formData)
    {
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]MyData formData)
    {
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string steamid { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string notetitle { get; set; }
    }

    public void Post(string value)
    {
    }

    public void Post1([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }
```

Comment: when you say this is not working, what is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: When Game Server send the POST, I am not getting it on app. but with Fiddler i can make sure the POST is being made : http://prntscr.com/bswyme

Comment: ah, you have all these `Post` actions all at once in your Controller? this might trip Web API as it won't know which one to chose for that request.

Comment: Ok i will try doing this too soon and check again 1 by 1, it was only the first one at first then i add 1 after another to test.

Comment: I CAN'T believe it actually worked ! i just did as i had and @MichaelDotKnox also said,but removed all the rest ! it got fixed .... wow so much time spend on this :D Thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object to receive the data in the body:

```
public class SteamData
{
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public ulong SteamId {get; set;}
    public string NoteTitle {get; set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

Then change your `Post` method like this:

```
public void Post([FromBody] SteamData data)
{
    if (!Program.settings.UnSub.Contains(steamid))
    {
        SteamID SID = new SteamID(data.SteamId);
        Program.steamFriends.SendChatMessage(SID, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, System.DateTime.UtcNow + " UTC ( GMT ) : " + data.NoteTitle);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Program.steamFriends.SendChatMessage(SID, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, data.Message);
    }
}
```

Then when the post happens, the data can more easily be in the body of the request.  WebAPI has difficulties retrieving more than one parameter with the [FromBody] attribute.  You can do it, but it's harder than it is worth.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I already did that actually, it was written bellow, It's  public class MyData and Post([FromBody]MyData formData) , you can see I made several      public void Post   each in a different way but i made a breakpoint for them all, and NON of them are getting a hit :(

Comment: @Pedram the problem might be that you have that many attempts in your controller. Clean it up so that it has a single "Post" action like @MichaelDotKnox described and see if it works. By the way, in this case you don't even need the `[FromBody]` attribute.

Comment: So yes, it worked this way, My problem was having so many of those Posts at same time.